# JavaScript Nested setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to write nested timed code with setInterval. I tried the following but no response from browser (Chrome and FF) whatsoever:

```
setInterval(function() {
    console.log('1');
    setInterval(function(){
          console.log('2');
    },5000);
}, 2500);
```

I expected the above code will wait for two seconds and half before starting, and then log('1'), then wait for five seconds, and log('2'). What happened is that I got no response from both browsers (why?)

Second point, I replaced console.log with window.alert. I got response this time. But not the desired. The first response I get is after 2 seconds and half, second response is after five seconds, but then the two functions start to happen simultaneously.

So, what I want to achieve: Two blocks of code, two different time intervals, and no simultaneous occurrence of both blocks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here but the result is that you will be infinitely creating timers. Can you give details of what you want to achieve as I can guarantee you that nested timers is not the correct way of doing it.

Comment: My guess is that you're after `setTimeout` rather than `setInterval`

Comment: I am trying to write code for repeated clicks on DOM elements.

Comment: That's still not enough information to help you. As it stands, this is an XY question where you're asking about the flaws in your attempted solution instead of the actual problem.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour is that your second setInterval is attached to context of the function of the first one.

So when the function of first setInterval end (is cleared), your second which was existing only in context of the function of first one disappear too

**EDIT**

You can use `window.setInterval( /*...*/ )` instead of your second setInterval to make it persist but the behaviour will be that each 2,5 second you create an interval which each 5 second call `console.log(2)` so you'll get a number of Interval growing which is not what you're asking for.

You may want to use `window.setTimeout( /*...*/ )` instead of your second setInterval. The behaviour will be the following :

1      (2.5sec)

1      (5 sec)

1      (7,5sec)

2      (7,5sec)   //1st nested

1      (10sec)

2      (10sec)    //2nd nested

...

Answer (score 2):

In your code an interval is created everytime the "outer" interval runs. In the example below the first interval will be created, and after a `timeout` of 2500ms the second one will be created.

```
setInterval(function(){
  console.log('1');
}, 2500);

setTimeout(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
    console.log('2');
  }, 5000);
}, 2500);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to call this both the operation only once, you are supposed to use setTimeout instead of setInterval.
Check below code:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('1');
    setTimeout(function(){
          console.log('2');
    },5000);
}, 2500);
```

this will log "1" after 2.5 sec and "2" after 7.5 sec (i.e. 2.5+ 5.0)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
var a=0;
setInterval(function() {
if(a==0){
 one();
  a++;
  }

  }, 2500);
 setInterval(function() {
two();
a=0;
}, 5000);
function one() {
console.log('1');
}
function two() {
 console.log('2');
 }
```

Answring from mobile not able to put code in good manner...well use a variable to make run 2500 set interval once ..i am provinding you a bin link...well above code works